# How do I use a formula I have in a Dictionary of formulas in a function

Tags: swift, dictionary, closures

I have a dictionary of formulas (in closures) that I now what to use in a function to calculate some results.

```
var formulas: [String: (Double, Double) -> Double] = [
    "Epley": {(weightLifted, repetitions) -> Double in return weightLifted * (1 + (repetitions)/30)},
    "Brzychi": {(weightLifted, repetitions) -> Double in return weightLifted * (36/(37 - repetitions)) }]
```

Now I'm trying to write a function that will get the correct formula from the dictionary based on the name, calculate the result, and return it.

```
func calculateOneRepMax(weightLifted: Double, repetitions: Double) -> Double {
    if let oneRepMax = formulas["Epley"] { $0, $1 } <-- Errors here because I clearly don't know how to do this part
    return oneRepMax
}

var weightlifted = 160
var repetitions = 2

let oneRepMax = Calculator.calculateOneRepMax(weightlifted, repetitions)
```

Now Xcode is giving me errors like 'Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by a ';' which tells me the syntax I'm trying to use isn't correct.

On a side note, I wasn't sure if I should use a dictionary for this but after a lot of homework I'm confident it's the correct choice considering I need to iterate through it to get the values when I need them and I need to know the number of key/value pairs so I can do things like display their names in a Table View.

I've searched far and wide for answers, read Apple's documentation over and over and I'm really stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formulas["Epley"]` returns an optional closure which needs to be
unwrapped before you can apply it to the given numbers. There are several options you can choose from:

*Optional binding* with `if let`:

```
func calculateOneRepMax(weightLifted: Double, repetitions: Double) -> Double {
    if let formula = formulas["Epley"]  {
        return formula(weightLifted, repetitions)
    } else {
        return 0.0 // Some appropriate default value
    }
}
```

This can be shortened with *optional chaining* and the
*nil-coalescing operator* `??`:

```
func calculateOneRepMax(weightLifted: Double, repetitions: Double) -> Double {
    return formulas["Epley"]?(weightLifted, repetitions) ?? 0.0
}
```

If a non-existing key should be treated as a *fatal error* instead
of returning a default value, then `guard let` would be
appropriate:

```
func calculateOneRepMax(weightLifted: Double, repetitions: Double) -> Double {
    guard let formula = formulas["Epley"] else {
        fatalError("Formula not found in dictionary")
    }
    return formula(weightLifted, repetitions)
}
```